# How to make IE8 display my custom icon font with CSS generated content

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

I've put up a test page illustrating my problem : http://www.heliopsis.net/var/fontcustom/

I've created a custom font with help from the awesome http://fontcustom.com/ but I have issues displaying it properly in IE8.

It seems that IE8 can use this font with HTML entities but not with CSS generated content. Even more puzzling, it sometimes manages to show the glyphs but loses them on page reload...

Does anybody know what's going on here ?

Here's a screenshot of what I see on IE8 :

[image: screenshot of missing font in IE8]

Comment: You should and your CSS to the post.

Answer (score 0):

In general, generated content doesn't work quite as well as it should (what does?) in IE8.

I played around a bit with your test page, and you might want to check that you aren't getting dumped off into IE8's compatability mode for IE7 or (even worse) Quirks Mode. Both of those seem to break the custom font, but I see it perfectly fine when IE8 runs as IE8.

To ensure that IE always gives to the most recent cababilities if possible add the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

meta to your header. Also, use the develper tools for IE8 to make sure that your font is being loaded when you see the issue.